# Replacing `\` with `\\` in ruby

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `\` with `\\`. Here was my first try:

```
> puts '\\'.gsub('\\', '\\\\')
\
```

I was pretty surprised when I saw the output. After some experimenting I was finally able to do what I wanted this this code:

```
> puts '\\'.gsub('\\', '\\\\\\')
\\
```

Why isn't the first piece of code working? Why do I need six backslashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'\\'.gsub('\\', '\\\\')
```

When the substitution occurs, the substitution string `'\\\\'` is passed by the **Regexp** engine, and `\\` is replaced by `\`. The substitution string ends up as `'\\'`, a single backslash.

---

The idomatic way to replace any single bachslach to double is to use:

```
str.gsub(/\\/, '\\\\\\\\\')  # 8 backslashes!
```

Comment: Oh, so here I have to escape twice - first for Ruby and then for its regex engine? Would '\\\\\\\\' be more correct?

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `Regexp.escape` to escape your `\`:

```
puts '\\'.gsub('\\', Regexp.escape('\\\\'))
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter

```
'\\'.gsub(/(\\)/, '\1\1')
```